# IndexError: string index out of range python problem

Tags: python

I'm working on a game that called 'i will guess the name ur thinking of ' or 'guess my name'.
The user will enter a letter and the program will try to guess what position of it by using a "for loop" in python:

```
list_of_names  = [ ]
userinput_letter = input('QUESTION : write a letter the name has: ')
new_list_of_names = [ ]
for names in list_of_names  :
  if userinput_letter in list_of_names  :
    new_list_of_names.append(names)
randomname = random.choice(new_list_of_names]
position_of_userletter = randomname.find(userinput_letter)
yn = input('QUESTION : does this letter "'+ userinput_letter +'" in the position "'+ str(position_of_userletter ) +'" (yes/no): ' )
if (yn == 'yes') :
    newlist_ofnames = [ ]
    for namesyes in new_list_of_names:
        if ( namesyes in userinput_letter [position_of_userletter] ) :
            newlist_ofnames.append(namesyes)
print(newlist_ofnames)
```

> IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: You should post the line where the error is

Comment: `for namesyes in new_list_of_names:
            if ( namesyes in userinput_letter [position_of_userletter] ) :
                newlist_ofnames.append(namesyes)`

Comment: First you have newlist_ofnames and after new_list_of_names . Is this what you have in your code?
Also userinput_letter is a string with 1 element, if you are going to search in a position that is bigger than 0 it will  crash

Comment: oh yes thanks for the information, also someone gave a solution im still a beginner xddd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand `userinput_letter` is just one letter and you are trying to get some index in it. That's why you are getting error.

You should do smth like

`if (len(namesyes) => position_of_userletter and namesyes[position_of_userletter] ==  userinput_letter):`

Answer (score 0):

First of all on line 5 you should have placed names instead of list_of_names.

Secondly you should place a loop that would re-run random choice if yn is equal to 'no'.

Then instead of this line:

```
    if ( namesyes in userinput_letter [position_of_userletter] ) :
```

place this line:

```
   if (namesyes[postition_of_userletter]== userinput_letter):
```

Hope it works :)